# Symfony 4.1 cache not being created

Tags: php, symfony, caching, file-permissions

I've recently upgraded Symfony to the new Symfony4.1.  As [seen over here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) we no longer need to setup file permissions anymore.  I ran the command:

```
php bin/console cache:warmup
```

And no errors came while running that.  However when I try and view the website. I get the following error.

```
Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/www/mywebsite.com/var/cache/prod)\n in /var/www/mywebsite.com/var/bootstrap.php.cache
```

Obviously this means that the new feature of Symfony4.1 is not working for me.  Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: did the cache warmup create the cache properly? and are you running on prod environment?

Comment: 4.1 no longer has a bootstrap.php.cache file. I take it you upgraded from 3.x?  Might be a few more tweaks needed.

Comment: @Dimitris, no. I'm 100% sure it didn't or else I wouldn't get that "write to cache" error.  Also I'm trying to run it currently it in DEV mode.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the info.  That file is indeed being created. I did update from Symfony 3.1 so I'll see what I'm missing.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably tried to tweak your 3.x composer.json file.  That has never worked for me.  When upgrading, I install a fresh S4 project and all my dependencies.  I then replace the old composer.json with the new one.  Just a suggestion.  I might add that the error you posted shows your app trying to run in prod mode.  Something else to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions to cache directory with bash command:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /path/to/cache_directory/
```